# How to increment variable names in jQuery in a LOOP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a insert a few `textbox` using loop as follow.

```
txtTimeIn1 txtTimeIn1 txtchkbox1
txtTimeIn2 txtTimeIn2 txtchkbox2
txtTimeIn3 txtTimeIn3 txtchkbox3
txtTimeIn4 txtTimeIn4 txtchkbox4
```

I like to check if txtTimeIn or txtTimeOut is empty. Hence I run a loop through all txtchkbox and when it is checked, I will check if txtTimeIn or txtTimeOut is empty. If so I will prompt user. The problem I have is the syntax please help. I have the following code.

```
 function checkempty() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
    if($('#txtchkbox' + i + ').val() != ''){
      if($('#txtTimeIn' + i + ').val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i + ').val() == ''){
        alert('Forgot to insert time ');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`$('#txtchkbox' + i + ').val() != ''` this part no sure how to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error at trailing single quote at

`$('#txtchkbox' + i + ')`

You can use attribute begins with selector to select all elements where `id` begins with `"txtTimeIn"`, or `"txtchkbox"`, `.is()` to check is the `.value` of any of the matched element is empty string `""`

```js
function checkempty() {
  if ($("[id^=txtTimeIn], [id^=txtchkbox]").is(function() {
    return this.value === "";
  })) {
    alert('Forgot to insert time ');
  }
}

$("[id^=txtTimeIn], [id^=txtchkbox]").on("keyup", checkempty)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="txtTimeIn1">
<input type="text" id="txtchkbox1">
<input type="text" id="txtTimeIn2">
<input type="text" id="txtchkbox2">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply, I have actually rows of txtTimeIn1, txtTime2, txtChkbox1 and so on. I only want to check those where txtChkbox is checked. How to do that?

Comment: You can use selector `"[id^=txtChkbox]"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error here

```
 if($('#txtTimeIn' + i + ').val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i + ').val() == ''){
```

this should be

```
 if($('#txtTimeIn' + i).val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i).val() == ''){
```

you can also use trim() on every `.val()` to clean up unwanted spaces

```
.val().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra single quote in all the if statement

```
function checkempty() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
    if($('#txtchkbox' + i + ').val() != ''){
      if($('#txtTimeIn' + i + ').val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i + ').val() == ''){
        alert('Forgot to insert time ');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

change it to

```
function checkempty() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
    if($('#txtchkbox' + i).val() != ''){
      if($('#txtTimeIn' + i).val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i).val() == ''){
        alert('Forgot to insert time ');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also check for the `length`

`$('#txtchkbox' + i).val().trim().length`

`.trim` will remove the space from the beginning or trailing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the both the if statements with the below codes respectively.

if($('#txtchkbox' + i).val() != '')

if($('#txtTimeIn' + i).val() == '' OR $('#txtTimeOut' + i).val() == '')

You don't need single quote concatenation after i as the the element ID string is already completed at i. Moreover, if any concatenation is started it should be completed too.